# How to enable gamma settings for second monitor?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, brightness

I would like to change gamma settings for the second monitor because it's too bright. On Ubuntu color calibration was kind of a pain because you required a calibrating device. KDE looks a lot friendlier but the drop down for display selection is greyed out (as shown on the snapshot, towards the bottom right corner). Any suggestions here how to enable that?

[image: screen1]

Comment: The little tool `xgamma` should do it.

Comment: Ok. Will have a try.